# Why am I getting this error "Invalid argument"?

Tags: javascript, drupal, internet-explorer-8, authorize.net

On one page I have an error that only happens in IE 8 (possibly other versions of IE, but 8 is what I have installed).

```
Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 31
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: https://verify.authorize.net/anetseal/seal.js
```

This error is causing the page to stop rendering and it just appears to keep loading (the tab has the loading icon and says "Connecting...").

This is the relevant code:

```
<div id="verisign"> 
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">var ANS_customer_id="myid_taken_out";</script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//verify.authorize.net/anetseal/seal.js" ></script> <a href="http://www.authorize.net/" id="AuthorizeNetText" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

This is referenced on uc_cart.pages.inc in the ubercart module.

Comment: what does your HTML markup look like?  What browser mode and compatibility mode are you using in IE 8?

Comment: It is not running in compatibility mode. What do you mean by browser mode? I will post the code in the question.

Comment: If you enable the script debugger and developer tools in IE, you'll get an option to go directly to the exact spot the error occurs on. Otherwise, the line/char numbers reported are pretty much outright random numbers in IE and utterly useless for debugging.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx

Comment: When I run the script debugger it gives me the same line (31) on the script https://verify.authorize.net/anetseal/seal.js

Comment: hit F12 in IE ... if you lose the browser window, hold down [ALT] + [SPACE] > then restore ... the window has been known to hide on me before.  Switch between the modes to narrow down the browser version.  It might also be good to put your script file references in the HTML head, and not in the div.  Keep us posted on what you find out.

Comment: @Mr. Wanta: I cannot use IE9... I'm running XP at work and cannot upgrade

Comment: I can't put it in the head, it's used for the Verisign logo to appear at a certain place. Also it happens no matter what option I choose (browser modes and document modes)

Comment: Man that code is bad with document.write out incomplete portions of tags. Yuck... Teach someone about building a string and writing once.

Comment: where is window.ANS_customer_id coming from?  can you put an alert on the line above that line like this: alert(window.ANS_customer_id);

Comment: It's comming from the first script tag

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, since they isn't a lot of infomation here; I think you have an extra comma in an object like this:

```
var obj = {t:0,a:1},
```

Trailing commas are parsed out by most browsers but it really screws up IE

Comment: The error is occurring in the js file on https://verify.authorize.net/anetseal/seal.js

Answer (score 0):

window.ANS_customer_id must be undefined

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.ANS_customer_id="myid_taken_out";</script>
```

It's possible that the way you had it set before wasn't resolving to window (like it should), depending on your browser. I've never seen that before, but being explicit doesn't hurt.

This is the line in that seal.js file that's breaking:

```
if( window.ANS_customer_id )
```

It's also possible that [my hair is a bird](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/your-argument-is-invalid).

Comment: The line that was breaking was 31... document.writeln( '</style>' );
According to IE debugger. And what do you mean your hair is not a bird?

Comment: Yeah but the debugger doesn't take comment lines into account, and there were two of those at the top of the file.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. The line in the first script tag is now: window.ANS_customer_id="myid"; I alerted window.ANS_customer_id after and it showed up fine.

Answer (score 0):

Remove their verified merchant seal snippet and contact Authorize.net to lodge a complaint/ticket.

I was a) happy to find that after debugging our site this evening for ~4 hours, in response to a crisis mode issue from customers, that removing it immediately restored our functionality on IE7/8 browsers (version 9, I believe is not affected, although I'm not 100% sure), then b) googled for problems and was shocked to find that the issue with Authorize.net's verified merchant seal snippet has been in force since at least 2011.

To be clear, today is January 29, 2013